# How to efficiently store data from react-quill to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-quill

I am making a simple blogging site using react, I am using `react-quill` and i can't figure out the best way to store the data from react-quill editor to the backend. From my code, the content I get is already formatted with `html` tags. I would like to store the data in a way that when It is stored efficiently and when retrieved from the server, it is displayed with all the formatting e.g bold text, italized... The sample code is below. Also if there is a way i can improve my code, feel free to tell me :)

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.bubble.css";

const Create = () => {
    const [body, setBody] = useState('');
    const handleBody = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        setBody(e)
    }
    return (
        <main>
            <div className="form-container">
                <form>
                    <h2>create post</h2>
                    <ReactQuill
                        placeholder='spread your message...'
                        modules={Create.modules}
                        formats={Create.formats}
                        onChange={handleBody}
                        value={body}
                    />
                    <button id="submit-btn">post</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

Create.modules = {
    toolbar: [
      [{ 'font': [] }],
      [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}],
      [{ 'align': [] }],
      [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
      ['link', 'image'],
      ['code-block'],
      ['clean']
    ]
};

Create.formats = [
    'font',
    'size',
    'bold', 'italic', 'underline',
    'list', 'bullet',
    'align',
    'color', 'background',
    'link',
    'image',
    'code-block'
  ];

export default Create;
```

Comment: store the data as string then on the frontend convert the string to html

Comment: also try to avoid react-quill because it is not maintained anymore and you can use tinymce as replacement also

Comment: [This tutorial from web dev simplified](https://youtu.be/iRaelG7v0OU) teaches how to use the quill editor and also saves the data on it to a backend using a socket, it might help you get an idea on what to do

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you use the delta property of quill.
This helps in saving the text  in json object in database. And if you want the text back with all format applied you can use JSON.parse().